# Audio and background blurring happening in the wrong order

Tags: java, android, audio, background

I have a button and if you click it the background should turn blurrish and a sound should be played. But for some reason, the blur doesn't apear until the sound has stopped.

Here is my code:

```
    daButton.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    daButton.setEnabled(false);
                    //System.out.println("Klickad!");
                    x++;

                    background.setAlpha(100);

                    rl.setBackground(background);


                    mpen.start();
                           mpen.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {


                               }
                           });
```

My Button is called "daButton", my background image is called "background", my RelativeLayout is called "rl" and my mediaplayer is called "mpen".

Answer (score 0):

try separete actions on different threads, because when you blur something and play sound, each action runs into Main Thread one after another

Comment: But why does the blur happen after the sound?